# JavaScript Mongodb :Print the name of employee(s) who make more than average salary of all employees

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to get the average salary for all employees and then compare that average to all the employee salaries in the collection and in the end print out the names of the employees with salaries greater than the average.

But i have to use javascript in mongodb.

I tried this and i was able to get the results but i used the Aggregation framework But i want to learn how i can do it JavaScript in Mongodb

```
db.emps.aggregate( [  {$group: {_id: "Ename", avgSal: {$avg: "$Sal"}  }}])
{ "_id" : "Ename", "avgSal" : 17060 }

var avgSal = 17060
db.emps.find( {Sal: {$gt: avgSal}}, {_id:0, Ename:1})
{ "Ename" : "Joe" }
{ "Ename" : "Jose" }
{ "Ename" : "Brian" }
{ "Ename" : "Tom" }
```

Here is how my collection looks like.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f3c"), "EID" : 2, "Ename" : "Jim", "Sal" : 14100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f3d"), "EID" : 1, "Ename" : "Joe", "Sal" : 20000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f3e"), "EID" : 3, "Ename" : "Bob", "Sal" : 13500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f3f"), "EID" : 4, "Ename" : "Amy", "Sal" : 12000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f40"), "EID" : 5, "Ename" : "George", "Sal" : 10000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f41"), "EID" : 6, "Ename" : "Kurt", "Sal" : 9000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f42"), "EID" : 7, "Ename" : "Saeed", "Sal" : 13000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f43"), "EID" : 8, "Ename" : "Jose", "Sal" : 40000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f44"), "EID" : 9, "Ename" : "Brian", "Sal" : 19000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bea22e2599db4fa75aa6f45"), "EID" : 10, "Ename" : "Tom", "Sal" : 20000 }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this and i was able to get the results but i used the Aggregation framework But i want to learn how i can do it JavaScript in Mongodb 
                                                                                           db.emps.aggregate( [  {$group: {_id: "Ename", avgSal: {$avg: "$Sal"}  }}])
{ "_id" : "Ename", "avgSal" : 17060 }

> var avgSal = 17060
> db.emps.find( {Sal: {$gt: avgSal}}, {_id:0, Ename:1})
{ "Ename" : "Joe" }
{ "Ename" : "Jose" }
{ "Ename" : "Brian" }
{ "Ename" : "Tom" }

Comment: Add this to your question so it's easier for people to read it and possibly post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fire two query.

1. The first query to find out the average salary.
2. The second query to find out employee have more than the average salary

   ```
    db.getCollection('emps').aggregate([
          {$group: {_id: null, Sal: {$avg: "$Sal"}}}

    ]).forEach(function(dd){
           db.getCollection('emps').find({Sal: {$gte: dd.Sal}}, {Ename: 1, _id: -1}).forEach(function(emp_name){print(emp_name)})
   })
   ```

Try above code, may be it will help you